# Apple App Store (install and get) loop, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, install

Apple App Store is stuck in a loop, when you press "get" you get "install", and when you press "install" you get "get" again, and so on with infinity loop, trying to download a free or commercial app — how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the problem came from fingerprint (Touch ID), as when I turned their options off, it worked like charm.

Just turn off those settings under "Touch ID & Passcode" section:
1. iPhone Unlock.
2. iTunes & App Store.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

I just confirmed from Apple Support Center that it cannot install apps even free ones if there is not a credit card on file.

So, if not, add the credit info and shipping address to your apple id in advance.

Comment: Still not fixed

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue on Mac App store when I tried to download a free app. It was looping between Get and Install. I tried all the above mentioned suggestions but what worked for me was signing out from my App store and logging back in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Install/Get loop problem. After lots of digging and resetting basically everything, I came upon my solution: it was the fake address I submitted when creating my Apple ID (literally just strings of random letters). I wasn't able to change it in the original ID, so I just made a new one where the zip code matched the state. That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using a test account from the Apple Developer program.  Once I changed back to my real account, I was able to install apps again.  To be clear, I'm talking about the Settings/iTunes & App Store/Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

Press the button on the right side of phone to lock it.
then log in using your passcode rather than your finger print.

Click install on the app you want and it will ask you for your finger print.

Press finger an you should be good to go.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck in a loop that's asking for you to review some terms, when you try and view an app in the appstore, and it leads you back to the app store, to fill in a field that should be username, but is actually a password field, try the following, as it helped me on an ipad:

- Go to the TV app or some other app that is owned by apple, and has your Apple Id in it.
- Click on your account, and then whatever option there is to view your account
- That will launch the appstore to review your account, and will show the correct fields, etc
- Then you'll be redirected back to the TV app, and should now be able to install apps like normal in the app store.

If that still doesnt work, try this first, then try the above again

Ensure you have a billing/shipping address setup

- Go to your apple id page, and ensure you have billing/shipping address setup at apple, here: https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage